# Should the tags 'pipe' and 'pipes' be merged and aliassed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981236/pipe-communication-in-c-problems) on StackOverflow about pipes, and was surprised to find the question tagged with both [pipe](/questions/tagged/pipe) and [pipes](/questions/tagged/pipes), where the counts are 'pipe × 216' and 'pipes × 417' (but only 4 questions are tagged with both).  I'm not willing to try a manual merge of these two - but I don't see a justification for keeping both.

Comment: Isn't there a niche product called "pipes"? If so, it deserves it's own tag. Here we are: [a yahoo product called "pipes"](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/). Looks like some kind of rss thing. Not familiar enough with it to say if it is on-topic on SO or not.

Comment: @dmckee: there is such a product, but I see only one question in the first page of 'tag pipes' output where the tag is used for Yahoo! Pipes (and one for Hadoop pipes) and the rest are Unix/Windows pipes.  I'd be OK with having 'pipe' for Unix/Windows pipes (noting that 'named-pipes' is used quite a lot too), and leaving 'pipes' documented as 'For Yahoo! Pipes, Hadoop Pipes, and generally anything not relating to Unix/Windows (named) pipes'.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: "named pipes" are something different as plain "pipes". The discussion should not mix them.

Comment: Absolutely; there are over 400 questions on SO tagged 'named-pipes', many of them without either 'pipe' or 'pipes', and there was never any intention of reorganizing those tags, nor 'yahoo-pipes'.  Strictly just the dual tags 'pipe' and 'pipes' (with about 600 entries each in February 2012).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wiki for both [pipe](/questions/tagged/pipe) and [pipes](/questions/tagged/pipes) described Unix pipes, so any misuse for Yahoo-Pipes and Hadoop-Pipes would not count IMHO. Also [yahoo-pipes](/questions/tagged/yahoo-pipes) already exists and has 174 uses.

Both [pipes](/questions/tagged/pipes) and [pipe](/questions/tagged/pipe) have over 600 uses each, there *should* be something done, but doing this by hand with plain "edit" - *uhm*

I think [pipes](/questions/tagged/pipes) and [pipe](/questions/tagged/pipe) should be merged and synonymized to avoid more confusion in the future. Reuse of only one form for anything else is misleading at best.